# I want to sell the rights to all 100+ of my artworks to a game developer or any other interested company

Tags: business, legal, licensing, contract, pricing

I'm an artist who is inexperienced to the world of art licensing. I have **136 artworks** in a similar art style, all of which are food.png graphics, and I can see them being useful to a game developer with cooking mechanics (I have raw ingredients, fruits, desserts, you name it).

I'd want to sell them to a business rather than let the artworks collect dust in my computer. But I'm not sure how to go about doing it. My inquiries are as follows:

1. Is it **my responsibility to draft the contract**?
2. How does the **online contract signing** work?
3. Is it acceptable to charge the customer $20 per artwork because I would be handing up all rights?

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: You & a million other hopefuls. Unless you can talk yourself through a few doors to present these as a portfolio, actually in person to a buyer, you'll be doing the same as everyone else these days & licensing them through one of the myriad online catalogues. You get paid if they get used. They do the contract. You have pretty much no power in this negotiation whatsoever.

Comment: Has the business inquired about your artwork? Or are you just wanting to cold call in the hopes of selling them (in which case see @Tetsujin 's comment)

Comment: @Scott - indeed, as a rather famous 'show-business' person once said to me, right at the start of my career. "Ah, so you were speaking to [huge name]. But… *who called who?*" ;)

Comment: As I see it you have 3 options: 1. You sell the drawings through some existing site on their terms. 2. You make your own site, formulate your own terms and conditions, setup a system for payment and somehow attract traffic to your site. 3. You find a client, by coincidence or through hard work, that needs exactly the drawings you have made and sell them to them like you would sell commissioned work. In my opinion only option 1 is realistic.